# javascript-How to do an area calculation with html forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, http-post

I need to calculate the area of a room and I can't find were is the problem in my  code. To be more specific I need to call the values from the form and when I press the submit button I want to print the area of the room based on my calculations.

Also getElementById doesn't seem to work, and I don't know why.

```js
function area() {
  var perimeter = document.getElementById("PE").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("He").value;
  var doors = document.getElementById("Nd").value;
  var doors_w_par = doors * 5.0212;
  var windows = document.getElementById("Nw").value;
  var windows_w_par = windows * 2.488;
  var closets = document.getElementById("Nc").value;
  var closets_w_par = closets * 1.37;
  var areas = (perimeter * height) - doors_w_par - windows_w_par - closets_w_par;
  return areas;
}
console.log(area());
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
  Perimeter:
  <input type="float" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="Pe" name="P" />
  <br/>height:
  <input type="float" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="He" name="H" />
  <br />doors:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="Nd" name="D" />
  <br />windows:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="Nw" name="W" />
  <br />closets:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="Nc" name="C" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="calc" name="sub" id="subm" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</form>
<br />
```

Comment: you need numbers, not strings. please use parseFloat.

Comment: Where is `testResults()` defined? Also note it's `Pe`, not `PE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot call area until the form exists
2. you need to not use a submit button but instead a type="button"
3. PE is Pe in your form
4. I do not believe form elements can have type="float" - "number" is what you might want or "text" or add the step attribute to the number
5. You need to parse the value returned depending on the calculation you make
6. use toFixed(decimals) to round the result

```js
function area() {
  var perimeter = document.getElementById("Pe").value;
  perimeter = isNaN(perimeter)||perimeter==""?0:parseFloat(perimeter);
  var height = document.getElementById("He").value;
  height = isNaN(height)||height==""?0:parseFloat(height)
  var doors = document.getElementById("Nd").value;
  doors=isNaN(doors)||doors==""?0:parseInt(doors,10);
  var doors_w_par = doors * 5.0212;
  var windows = document.getElementById("Nw").value;
  windows=isNaN(windows)||windows==""?0:parseInt(windows,10);
  var windows_w_par = windows * 2.488;
  var closets = document.getElementById("Nc").value;
  closets=isNaN(closets)||closets==""?0:parseInt(closets,10);
   var closets_w_par = closets * 1.37;
  var areas = (perimeter * height) - doors_w_par - windows_w_par - closets_w_par;
  return areas.toFixed(2);
}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("subm").onclick=function() {
    console.log(area());
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
  Perimeter:
  <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="Pe" name="P" />
  <br/>height:
  <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="He" name="H" />
  <br />doors:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="Nd" name="D" />
  <br />windows:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="Nw" name="W" />
  <br />closets:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="9999999999999" id="Nc" name="C" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="calc" name="sub" id="subm" />
</form>
<br />
```